# STI MySQL fun select as with case

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, sti

I have the following STI setup:

```
class Cage < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :animals
end

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cage
end

class Cat < Animal
  # name = "Tom"
end

class Mouse < Animal
  # name = "Jerry"
end
```

I would like to do a select on the Animals table that returns the following structure:

```
+----+-----------------------+
| ID | cat_name | mouse_name |
+----+-----------------------+
| 1  | Tom      | Jerry      | 
+----+-----------------------+
```

Ideally I would like something like this:

```
Cage \
  .joins(:animals)
  .select("
    cages.id,
    animals.name as case animals.type 
      when 'Mouse' then mouse_name 
      when 'Cat' then cat_name end
  ") \
  .group('cages.id')
```

But that doesn't work so I did this:

```
Cage \
  .joins(:animals)
  .select("
    cages.id,
    case animals.type when 'Mouse' then animals.name end mouse_name end,
    case animals.type when 'Cat' then animals.name cat_name end
  ") \
  .group('cages.id')
```

Is there a way to make the first query work and if not is there a better/alternative way to write the second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first query you're trying to make two name columns with one `CASE` expression. That won't work. If you want two cols in your resultset, you have to select two different things.

Your second query is closer, but you're doing a group-by without any aggregate functions in the select, so you could get a random result from each group. I suggest:

```
...
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(animals.type='Cat',animals.name,NULL)) AS cat_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(IF(animals.type='Mouse',animals.name,NULL)) AS mouse_name
...
```

If I'm misunderstanding and you actually want both names in one result column, you could do:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( 
    CONCAT(animals.type,' name is: ',animals.name) 
    SEPARATOR ', '
) AS animal_names
```